# Postman- How to save token value from Header Authorization

Tags: postman, token

I have to create a series of GET - POST-GET request over Postman.
Here are the steps I am trying to implement:

1) GET - with base64 encoded authorization : through this I will get a token

2) POST - using the token received in Step1.

Now I want to know how can I save the token I am getting from step1 into an environment variable and further call the environment variable in step2.

Please refer to the Image to understand how I am receiving the token from step 1.[image]

Below is how I am trying to save the variable in Tests,(not sure if this is correct)

```
var jsonData = JSON.parse(Headers);
pm.setEnvironmentVariable("token",jsonData.message.token);
```

Comment: Is the token value in the response body or always in the response headers?

Answer (score 3):

As the reference looks like you're trying to get something from the response body, I'm assuming it looks something like this:

```
{
    "message": {
        "token": "qwerty123456"
    }
}
```

In the script, you would use something like this:

```
var jsonData = pm.response.json();
pm.environment.set("token", jsonData.message.token);
```

Comment: and don't forget to change you "Authorization" field in the request-header to this value

"Token {{token}}"

in order to be access the previously created environment variable.

Answer (score 3):

One image, thousand words

[image]
[image]

[image]

Get global variable: {{token}}

[image]